# Destroying Web Configuration Object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, web-config, config

How do we destroy web configuration object after the following?

```
Configuration config =WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath);
config.Save();
```

I'm having

> *The configuration file has been changed by another program.*

Comment: What you are actually trying to do ?

Comment: when you are getting this error

Comment: Actually the problem is a bit complex: I'm editing a web application's config file(s) when updating authorization rules. One procedure I have, adds a rule as a location tag if the location tag does not exist in the web.config by opening the web.config as XmlDocument and adding location/system.web/authorization tag into it, saving and then reopening the same file as Configuration object making relevant rule changes and then saving it.

Comment: I get the above error after this process and I thought that this may be happening because of opening a config file as config object first then reopening it as xmldocument and then reopening again as config object without destroying the vars used. I'm not sure if I were clear?! Any questions?